Looking for a digital mixer with 5-6 stereo AUX sends for personal IEM (Alternative to Zoom LiveTrak L-20)
Our band wants stereo IEM monitoring with individual mixes for each member (at least 5 stereo AUX sends, ideally 6).
We need to connect:

Electronic Drum Set (stereo out)
Bass guitar (mono out from processor)
Electric guitar (stereo out from processor)
Electric piano (stereo out)
3 mics for vocal
1 mic for sax
Metronome click from phone
(possibly stereo backing track)

Zoom LiveTrak L-20 looks like an ideal choice - it has 6 stereo AUX sends with the ability to connect stage monitors or stereo headphones.
But I am unsure if this mixer is good for band live gigs since I can see two big disadvantages:

Each channel has only 3-Band EQ (mid-parametric only) + low-cut filter.
Each channel has single-knob compression (no way to set ratio) and as I understand from the manual, the amount of compression can not be controlled via the iPad app, only on the mixer by the physical knob.

My questions:

Has anyone had experience with this mixer for live band gigs?
Is its band EQ enough for good live sound?
Is the compressor usable for vocals, guitars, and electronic drums?
Can anyone suggest good alternatives for Zoom LiveTrak L-20 with a similar amount of inputs and 5-6 stereo AUX sends for IEM, and better EQ/Compressor settings?


Yamaha TF1 ? Maybe not the same price range ...

For your IEM, 3 band EQ should be fine. You don't need to finely EQ your monitors - nobody ever does with stage wedges.

EDIT: I had missed the requirement for stereo Aux buses. The XR-18 has 6 mono buses.
The Behringer XR-18 has:

similar price
4-band fully parametric EQ
flexible compressor
6 mono Aux sends
if more are necessary, you can use Behringer P-16M IEM mixers
can be operated from a laptop, tablet or phone

It could still be used: create 4 mixes using the 6 Aux and 2 main buses, and buy 2x P-16M for the remaining two mixes. This will increase the cost of the solution.

It seems the aux sends are mono only on this product ?

Yes. I missed the stereo requirement in the question.
